# NASM x86_64 Remove new line character and add 0 at the end of string

Tags: linux, nasm, x86-64

how would you remove the new line character that is added at the end of the string when you get it from the console by using system read?
I would like to add a 0 to the end of it to use that string to open a file

I'm getting input like this:

```
mov     rdx,name_len    ; size_t count
mov     rsi,name        ; char *buf
mov     rdi,0           ; int fd, 0 for stdin
mov     rax,0           ; system read
syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` returns the number of characters, so you can index into the buffer and check if the last one read is a newline.  Or just unconditionally overwrite it with `0` with this:

```
...
syscall                       ; rax = sys_read(0, buf, max_len)
mov byte [rsi + rax - 1], 0
```

That assumes no error and that the input string was submitted with a newline instead of EOF.

(Linux `syscall`s preserve all regs except RAX (return value), and RCX/R11, so RSI still holds `name`.)